# Phonegap handleOpenURL not called on app launch (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, phonegap-build

Getting alert message when app is open in background.When I close the app from background when I launch the app it don't give me alert message. handleOpenURL not able to invoke in JavaScript when app is first time launch. Following are code

**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Code**

```
NSURL* url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
NSString* invokeString = nil;

 if (url) {
invokeString = [url absoluteString];
NSLog(@"iPaperReeder launchOptions = %@", url);
}

self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;
```

**AppDelgate.m**

```
if (!url) { return NO; }
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.setTimeout(function(){ handleOpenURL(\"%@\"); }, 1)", url];
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

// all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be  called 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

return YES;
```

**It should output to this javascript function:**

```
 function handleOpenURL(url) { 
alert('invoke: ' + url);
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's Working use Cordova  3.6 version.Not working in higher version 3.7 cordova

Comment: Try increasing the setTimeout from 1 to 1000 and see if the problem persists. It feels to me like the webview is not fully loaded when you try it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not doing right, Please follow my code as below:

You can easily sort out this problem.

In `"CDVHandleOpenURL.m"` file you need to change code as below :

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){if (typeof handleOpenURL === 'function') { handleOpenURL(\"%@\");}});", url];
```

To

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"if (typeof handleOpenURL === 'function') { handleOpenURL(\"%@\");} else { window._savedOpenURL = \"%@\"; }", url, url];
```

this will work perfectly.

Best of luck